# Android Studio gives redundant cast warning, but it's not really redundant

Tags: java, android

In my code I call:

```
myArray[ (Integer) compoundButton.getTag() ] = true;
```

and it works. However Android Studio gives me an warning saying that casting to (Integer) is redundant. However if I remove the cast it throws an error due to incompatible types int & java.lang.Object. Have I done something wrong and what can I do to remove this warning?

Comment: When you look at the message, what does Android Studio say to correct it? Also, run inspections: Analyze -> Inspect Code and it will most likely fix it for you.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I came across the issue with Analyze -> inspect Code, thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing with your code, apparently AS is wrong here, same result on my machine, and not Android related.

```
int[] ints = new int[] {};
Object foo = new Object();
ints[((int) foo)] = 1; // complains
```

(You probably want to cast to `int` (not `Integer`), but that will not solve the issue.)

BTW, if you extract a variable

```
int indexFromTag = (int) button.getTag();
myArray[indexFromTag];
```

AS will not complain.

Comment: Hmm, I'm glad to know I'm not the only one with this problem. Extracting works to remove that pesky error, thank you.

Comment: It's really weird. `ints[((Integer) foo)] = 1;` is not ok but `System.out.println(ints[((Integer) foo)]);` apparently is.